# How to build good security architecture in web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to do dynamic security in application (spring boot, spring mvc, spring security, thymeleaf).

I want add in my web app page where user/admin can add some new permissions (only names).
In another page he will be able to add e.g. new position in menu (or new field, or new tab).
And when he add this new item he should have option to chose what permissions users should have to see this new menu position (for field there will be one permission for view, and one for edit).

Do You have some sollutions how to do somethin like this?
I was thinkig about ALC in spring security but I don't now is this a good chose.

Mayby there is a way to use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole()")`?
Or add something like "component" table when I will put all itmes that users add. And in this table there will be column like "edit permission" and "view permissions" where I will put id's of permissions and check this table in all methots where I get menu items, fields ..

Mayby good solution for this will bee own implementation PermissionEvaluator?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need create ***role enum*** with ***permission*** table in the database.

1. Roles enum

   > ```
   > public enum Roles {
   >    Admin,
   >    Pm,
   >    TeamLead,
   >    User,
   >    ...
   > }
   > ```
2. Permission table

> **`| ID |   ROLE   |    WORKSPACE   |  READ  |  WRITE  | DELETE |`**
>   `|  1 |   Admin  |    Dashbord    |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  2 |   Admin  |    Employee    |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  3 |   Admin  |     Project    |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  4 |   Admin  |      Task      |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  5 |   Admin  |      Team      |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  6 |    Pm    |    Dashbord    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `|  7 |    Pm    |    Employee    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `|  8 |    Pm    |     Project    |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `|  9 |    Pm    |      Task      |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `| 10 |    Pm    |      Team      |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 11 | TeamLead |    Dashbord    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 12 | TeamLead |    Employee    |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `| 13 | TeamLead |     Project    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 14 | TeamLead |      Task      |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 15 | TeamLead |      Team      |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | TRUE   |`
>   `| 16 |   User   |    Dashbord    |  FALSE |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 17 |   User   |    Employee    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 18 |   User   |     Project    |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`
>   `| 19 |   User   |      Task      |  TRUE  |  TRUE   | FALSE  |`
>   `| 20 |   User   |      Team      |  TRUE  |  FALSE  | FALSE  |`

3. You users table in database must add **userRole** column

> `@Basic`
>   `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`
>   `private Roles userRole;`

4. Create custom annotation interface check current user by role permission

   > @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
   >   public @interface PermissionCheck
   >   {
   >
   > ```
   > String[] workspace() default {};
   >
   > boolean read() default false;
   >
   > boolean write() default false;
   >
   > boolean delete() default false; }
   > ```

> @Aspect @Component public class PermissionAspect {
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> private PermissionRepository permissionRepository;
>
> @Around("execution(@com.security.annotation.springbootsecuritypermission
> ```
>
> .aspect.PermissionCheck
>   * *(..)) && @annotation(permissionCheck)")
>       public Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, PermissionCheck >permissionCheck) throws Throwable {
>           if(permissionCheck.workspace().length>0
>                   && SecurityUtil.getUser()!=null){
>              List permissionList = permissionRepository.findByRolesAndWorkspaceIn(
>                       SecurityUtil.getUser().getRoles(),permissionCheck.workspace());
>
> ```
>        Function<PermissionEntity,Boolean> permissionFunction = new Function<PermissionEntity, Boolean>() {
>            @Override
>            public Boolean apply(PermissionEntity permissionEntity) {
>                if(permissionCheck.read() && permissionEntity.getRead()) {
>                    return true;
>                }
>                if(permissionCheck.write() && permissionEntity.getWrite()) {
>                    return true;
>                }
>                if(permissionCheck.delete() && permissionEntity.getDelete()) {
>                    return true;
>                }
>                return false;
>            }
>        };
>
>        final boolean[] hasPermission = {false};
>        permissionList.forEach(permissionEntity -> {
>            hasPermission[0] = permissionFunction.apply(permissionEntity);
>            if(hasPermission[0]){
>                return;
>            }
>        });
>
>         if(!hasPermission[0]){
>             throw new AccessDeniedException("Do not has permission");
>         }
>
>     }
>     return pjp.proceed();
> } }
> ```

5. You can use custom annotation on methods

   > @GetMapping("dashboard") @PermissionCheck(workspace =
   >   {Workspace.DASHBOARD},read = true) public String dashboard() {
   >   return "dashboard"; }

If do not understand me very well you can open this link https://github.com/Dilsh0d/spring-boot-security-permission.